# "Не( )важно" - слитно или раздельно?

Tags: слитно-раздельно

> Сделать уборку самим или привлечь специальную фирму - не()важно.

Comment: По-моему, предложение нужно как-то переформулировать. Ни с слитным, ни с раздельным написанием "не/важно" понятным оно не будет. Может, я и не прав...

Answer (score 2):

***Сделать уборку самим или привлечь специальную фирму - неважно.***

По правилу стоит писать *слитно*.
http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/38.htm#%D0%B7_09

> Пишутся слитно с "не" наречия на -о, которые в сочетании с "не" приобретают противоположное значение; обычно *такие слова можно заменить синонимами без -не*.

В таком случае  появляется новое слово с противоположным значением. Отрицания в предложении не будет.

У нас и синоним подобрать можно без изменения смысла: неважно = безразлично.

Однако и раздельное написание ошибкой не будет: в таком случае будет подчёркнуто отрицание важности.

Правда, раздельное написание на практике встречается значительно реже, а потому "неважно" всё же предпочтительнее писать *слитно*.

Answer (score 1):

Ответ дополнен.

***Сделать уборку самим или привлечь специальную фирму — это неважно.***

Я согласна с Игорем и тоже выбираю слитную форму письма, но этому предложению явно не хватает местоимения "это".

**Пояснение ответа (как решаются такие задачи)**

1. Проверка семантики форм ***не важно*** и ***неважно***

Формы могут совпадать по смыслу, а могут не совпадать, поэтому проверяем  по словарю Ефремовой. ***Неважно***, предикатив. Оценочная характеристика чего-либо как несущественного, незначительного, **не имеющего** большого значения, не заслуживающего внимания. ***Важно***, предикатив. Оценка какой-л. ситуации, чьих-л. действий как **имеющих** большое значение, заслуживающих особого внимания. Делаем вывод, что **семантика форм совпадает.**

**Для сравнения:** ***недалеко*** – почти близко, ***не далеко*** – на среднем расстоянии. Здесь семантика форм не совпадает уже на уровне слов/словосочетаний.

2. При совпадении значений  следует использовать утвердительную форму ***неважно,***  а вот необходимость **отрицания** надо доказывать. Что мы, собственно говоря, отрицаем или, другими словами, подчеркиваем? Можно отрицать другое суждение, которое уже высказано или будет высказано далее; можно что-то сравнивать — раньше было важно, а теперь уже не важно. В любом случае желательно видеть контекст.

**Общий же принцип** заключается в том, что данном предложении (или в сопутствующем тексте) что-либо может показаться важным, а это не так. Поэтому отрицание  всегда связано **с  противопоставлением** (явным или скрытым): это неважно, а важно что-то другое.

3. Но даже если мы решили обозначить отрицание, то есть выделить его **логическим ударением**, то нужно подобрать соответствующую **структуру** предложения, где это **можно сделать**. Обычно у предикативных наречий свободная позиция для выбора **в начале предложения**, например: ***Не важно**, будем ли мы делать уборку сами или привлечем фирму, но желательно делать это вовремя, то есть составить для себя определенный график.*
4. Это тот пример, где возможно выразить отрицание, а вот в приведенном предложении позиция у наречия **явно утвердительная**.  Кстати, здесь **инверсия** следующего предложения:  *Это **неважно** – сделать уборку самим или привлечь специальную фирму.*  Оно утвердительное и в таком виде, а выделить логическим ударением предикатив  в конце заданного предложения вообще довольно затруднительно.
5. **И вывод.** В большинстве случаев подобные задачи решаются чисто **формально,** по каким-то общим правилам. При **единственном** решении  эти правила работают, но только **не при наличии вариантов**. Тогда нам приходится искать синонимы, учитывать статистику письма и т.д., но всё это **не имеет отношения к истине.**

Выбор формы написания НЕ  обычно делается **на уровне слова**,  а это задача **из области синтаксиса.** Нам кажется, что мы можем написать НЕ слитно или раздельно и таким  образом выразить отрицание или утверждение. Но это решение будет обозначено только **на бумаге**, в то время как оно должно восприниматься **на слух**, то есть присутствовать **в структуре** предложения.